# Problem facing in Home Assistant and Google assistant integration

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, home-assistant

I am having below two issue,
The below one observed from IFTTT make an web request,
1.Applet skipped "If You say "Open Binny", then Make a web request".Unable to make web request: Error: ETIMEDOUT
"I am using this URL http://192.168.43.184:8123/api/services/shell_command/test_cmd?api_password=solo@123"
The below one is observed in home assistant while we call service
2.homeassistant.components.shell_command] Error running command: `pwd`, return code: 1
can you solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IP (192.168.43.184) you are using in your http-request is a private internal IP (it will only work wthin your home network). You need to use your public (external) IP from your internet router (hopefully you have a public one). But even then, it will not work until you configure your router for a port forwarding, so if a request hit's your external IP (and port) your router should know which server (here 192.168.43.184) should be reached. You need a port forwarding like this: If a TCP conncetion comes to your public IP on port 8123 route it further to 192.168.43.184:8123

But I would suggest to get a DNS-entry like from DynDNS.org because your public IP will maybe change, and then you always have to adapt the IFTTT-URLs. With an DNS-entry you get rid of changing all the URLs out there. Often there is a tool which runs in your lokal network and checks if your public IP has changed and informes DNS-provider and updates the mapping between your DNS entry and your public IP

Answer (score 0):

You need a secure remote connection. You can use duckdns and https cert created with [dehydratated](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated)

https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2017-08/10-homeassistant_duckdns_letsencrypt

You can try the new tutorial https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/google_assistant/ for google assistant connection